# How to sort a listview by 3 keys

Tags: flutter

I tried to move a listview item to the right place after its status was changed.
It does not matter whether it is deleted, inserted, or just moved.
The issue is to find the right place/order on a list.

Let's say that list elements have three keys: status, category, and name.

```
status category name
0      a        item1
0      b        item2   -->
1      a        item3
1      c        item4
```

Let's say that item2 status has changed from 0 to 1. I would need to sort the entire list by status, category, and name or find the right place to move the item2, in this case should go like this:

```
status category name
0      a        item1
1      a        item3
1      b        item2   <--
1      c        item4
```

I tried to do this with .sort, but I do not see in the documentation that it allows multiple sort keys.

Could you please advise on how can I do this in Flutter?

---

UPDATE 1

Please look at the code bellow...

```
class ListDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListDetailsPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ListDetailsPage> createState() => _ListDetailsPageState();
}


class _ListDetailsPageState extends State<ListDetailsPage> {


  Future<List<PostListDetails>> postsFuture = getPosts();

  static Future<List<PostListDetails>> getPosts() async {

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    ...
    
    Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://somehost.com/api.php'),
      headers: <String, String>{
      ....
      },
      ....
    );

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
    ....
    }else {
        ....
    }

    final List body = json.decode(response.body);
    return body.map((e) => PostListDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();


  }


  void saveStatus(String nazwa, int status) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = ...;
    final listID = ...;

    try{
      Response response = await post(Uri.parse('https://somehost.com/api.php'),
        headers: <String, String>{
        ...
        },
        body: <String, String>{
        ...
        },
      );

      if(response.statusCode == 200){

        // ---> TODO refresh Lists here



      }else {
    ...
      }
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<PostListDetails>>(
          future: postsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final posts = snapshot.data!;
              return buildPosts(posts);
            } else {
              return const Text("No data...");
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget buildPosts(List<PostListDetails> posts) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('XXXXXXX'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: signUserOut,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: posts.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final post = posts[index];
            return Container(
            ...
            Checkbox(
                                  value: Int2Bool(post.status!.toInt()),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {post.status = Bool2Int(value!);});
                                    saveStatus(post.nazwa!, post.status!);
                                int customCompare(List<PostListDetails> a, List<PostListDetails> b) {
                                  if (a.status != b.status) {
                                    return a.status - b.status;
                                  }

                                  final int categoryCompare = a.category.compareTo(b.category);

                                  if (categoryCompare != 0) {
                                    return categoryCompare;
                                  }

                                  return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
                                }


                                  },
                                )
            ...
            )
    ...
```

I do not know how to declare function properly and to be more specific what to put instead of *ListItem*. I thought *`List<PostListDetails>`* would be OK, but is not and I cannot see a.status and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a custom compare function:

```dart
int customCompare(ListItem a, ListItem b) {
  if (a.status != b.status) {
    return a.status - b.status;
  }

  final int categoryCompare = a.category.compareTo(b.category);
  
  if (categoryCompare != 0) {
    return categoryCompare;
  }

  return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
}

// Sort the list using the custom compare function
items.sort(customCompare);
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, however I do not know what to put instead of ListItem in function declaration. Could you please look at the above code and advice how to integrate this function. Sorry for this, but I have a week experience with flutter/dart and many things are in fog for me yet.

Comment: OK... I just removed List and left PostListDetails what solved my issue :) for now...